# ngnix + gunicorn throws truncated response body

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I request some json data by some url, sometimes it works fine and sometimes doesn't ... I looked another related cuestion here, but it seems to recommend not change content-length by middleware ... my json data incomplete is as image below shows:

[image]

my app nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_error.log;

    location / {
    client_max_body_size 400M;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```

gunicorn script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/apps/myapp

LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/myapp.log
LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
NUM_WORKERS=3
# user/group to run as
USER=ubuntu
GROUP=ubuntu
cd /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp
source /home/ubuntu/.venv/myapp/bin/activate

export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

export NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=/home/ubuntu/newrelic/newrelic.ini

test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
exec /usr/local/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /home/ubuntu/.venv/myapp/bin/gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=$LOGFILE -b 127.0.0.1:8888 2>>$LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well ... I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774914/1911787), and I added `proxy_buffering off;` to config file and this solve the problem for my case.

the file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_error.log;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 400M;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for researching this. I've had a similar issues with huge Bokeh JSON objects, and this worked properly. This fix immediately corrected the issue!