# Python Django truncates the response

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I've created a little Django application and deployed it on Ubuntu,
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
import psycopg2
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit
def create_connection():
    return psycopg2.connect(database="data",user="ag",host="localhost",port=5432,password='pass')

def execute_query(query, parameters):
    with create_connection() as connection:
        result = []
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        for row in cursor:
            result.append(row)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            result[i] = list(result[i])
            for j in range(len(result[i])):
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] if result[i][j] else ""
        return result

@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='10/m')
def to_csv(request):
    j_body = json.loads(request.GET.get('data', ''))
    query = j_body['query']
    print(query)
    print("****************************************************************")
    parameters = j_body['params']
    headers = j_body['headers']
    rows = execute_query(query, parameters)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text_csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="result.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(rows)
    return response
```

The main goal of this app - to get sql query and return csv response as file, which size can be more than 200 mb. I have a problem - my response is always truncated to 696 kb (regardless on count of rows in result of cursor.execute). There is example. You can see the last truncated line.
[image: Example]

Server was ran by 'python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000' command.
Please, help me to solve my problem.

**UPDATED**
I redeployed it with Nginx and gunicorn, and tried solution suggested here 
[ngnix + gunicorn throws truncated response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732103/ngnix-gunicorn-throws-truncated-response-body)
Despite this, I am still getting the same error

I fixed my code, following this article - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files

```
#Also changed execute_query method, so it doesn't create redurant copy of response from database
def execute_query(query, parameters):
    with create_connection() as connection:
        result = []
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        return cursor

class Echo(object):
    """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    """
    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value

@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='10/m')
def to_csv(request):
    try:
        j_body = json.loads(request.GET.get('data', ''))
        query = j_body['query']
        print("****************************************************************")
        parameters = j_body['params']
        headers = j_body['headers']
        cursor = execute_query(query, parameters)
        pseudo_buffer = Echo()
        writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        print('Writing began')
        response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow(row) for row in cursor),
                                     content_type="text/csv")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="result.csv"'
        print('Sending began')
        return response
    except:
        return HttpResponse('Error')
```

Now all work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might need a [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects). Have you tried implementing this? It appears that you are suffering from some sort of issue with a buffered/chunked response. Something like gunicorn or nginx could be used to increase this buffer size, but it is not a real solution.