# Rails application Error Incomplete response received from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 applications ruby on rails in shared hosting, one of them SOMETIMES throw an error:

White screen and message:

> Incomplete response received from application

I can't reproduce the error, only sometimes the application throw the error.

In the application log there aren't any error.

How you said me in the comments I search for config/secrets.yml. This doesn't exist in my application.

I create this with the config/initializer/secret_token.rb.
My config/secrets.yml:

```
    development:
            secret_key_base: "key in secret_token"

    test:
            secret_key_base: "key in secret_token"

    production:
            secret_key_base: "key in secret_token"
```

Then I deleted secret_token and restart server: "touch tmp/restart.txt".

The error still appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241053/incomplete-response-received-from-application-from-nginx-passenger

Comment: My application works, only sometimes throws this error

Comment: So, despite your comment, can you confirm that you do have a `SECRET_KEY_BASE` set for your app?

Comment: I haven't, I put it but the same error again.