# Incomplete response received from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I want to deploy my rails app using phusion passenger in test environment DB. I have configured the following lines in my database.yml

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: testdb
  username: testuser
  password: pass
  host: x.x.x.x
```

when I start the passenger "passenger start -a x.x.x.x -p 3000 -d -e test" it started working. but when I open the application URL in browser it should me an error like "Incomplete response received from application". I don't know what will be the problem? I have searched well in SO. only they have provide solution for production mode. but I want to run the application in test mode. I am able to run in development mode. when I try to run in test mode only it showed the error. please help to get rid from this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: This url might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241053/incomplete-response-received-from-application-from-nginx-passenger

Comment: No its for production mode.i have refered this link. this is not much useful for me

Comment: Can you post your Rails logs and the logs of the webserver (nginx?)?

Comment: Hey..did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

don't forget make a secret key in your production server

```
$ rake secret
```

and define it in your "config/secrets.yml"

```
production:
  secret_key_base: "your key result from rake secret command "
```

Greeting

Comment: Actually it is not a problem....if you run your app in test mode and you get "Incomplete response received from application" error then your error will be saved in app/log file. but in view, it will show the "Incomplete response error"

Comment: Not always a case, it is necessary to check Nginx logs. I got same error because of no free disk space on the server, not because secret key settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your Production Rails_env is not setup properly.

To solve this issue open file `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and change the rails_evn to development.

if you want to solve this issue in Production environment.
Edit file `/rails_application/config/secrets/yml` and set the production `secret_key_base` what you can generate running `rake secret` in your terminal.

And restart your nginx server. using command `sudo service nginx restart`