# Rails App Error Message "Incomplete response received from application" AFTER successful Heroku Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, incomplete-type

First, I've been trying to solve this for days and have seen, and tried, a lot of posts on stack. My problem persists.  Plainly, my app works fine locally but when I access the site after a successful deploy to Heroku I'm getting this message in the upper left corner of the page, and nothing else, making it a little harder to troubleshoot. After following this tutorial to [deploy to Ubuntu](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04) on Digital Ocean seems to be about when things started going bad. I've tried answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395157xx/incomplete-response-received-from-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241053xx/incomplete-response-received-from-application-from-nginx-passenger), as well as a handful of other similar posts, but NOTHING has worked. Initially I was getting a missing arguments message from Heroku, but followed other suggestions which seemed to fix that but lead me to the current issue.  Not sure how much longer I can hide behind the "I'm a Ruby Noob" excuse, but after a year deployment seems to be the bain of my existence. I suspect it has something to do with setting of ENV variables but no fixes have worked yet for me. Reveal Variables have been manually set on Heroku.   secrets.yml, application.yml and database.yml files are in my .gitignore.

Some other noteworthy items - I'm using figaro to manage environmental varibles. I have an S3 bucket to store images set up using Railscast Pro#383, Carrierwave and Fog handling uploads. Again, this was working at some point earlier.

Has anyone gotten this error or know how I can acutely resolve it?

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
  config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' 

  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]                        # required
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME"]                          # required

end
```

config/application.yml

```
production:

  AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME: 'my_aws_secret_bucket_name_from_s3_manually_installed_on_heroku'

  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'my_aws_secret_access_key_id_from_s3_manually_installed_on_heroku'

  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'my_aws_secret_access_key_from_s3_manually_installed_on_heroku'

  SECRET_KEY_BASE: 'my_secret_key_base_generated_from_doing_rake_secrets'
```

config/secrets.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: some_random_#_for_dev

test:
  secret_key_base: some_random_#_for_test

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

.gitignore

```
# Ignore application configuration
config/application.yml

# Ignore secrets configuration
config/secrets.yml

# Ignore database configuration
config/database.yml
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace from the heroku logs?  Also what do you mean you followed a tutorial on how to deploy with digital ocean?  I may be showing my ignorance but I though digital ocean and heroku were mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes, they are @ruby_newbie. Just painting the picture, so to speak. My goal was to publish to the remote svr. The site was already on Heroku, but I think some of the changes that I made trying to launch to the Digital Ocean instance caused some issues with my Heroku instance.  Doing more research, when commenting out 2 lines in 'config/initializers/assets.rb' file I get an app error.  Not sure how to get to my stack trace from the command line. Trying 'heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=debug' is returning a "Couldn't find that app" message. Is this fubar? Thx for any guidance/help.

Comment: Heroku logs --tail will get you the logs.   Can you add the stack trace please?

Comment: I appreciate your input but I want to be clear that the reason for my question is that Heroku is saying that the app is successfully deployed. It's only when I go to the URL where a page is shown that says "Incomplete response received from application", so I don't have any exceptions to work with, or at least I'm unaware of how to invoke them.

Comment: So if you type "heroku logs --tail" into your terminal you see the logs correct?  Then when you visit the page and get the error message you see nothing in the logs at all?