# Incomplete response received from application - Passenger & NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, nginx, passenger

I have successfully installed rails with Passenger+Nginx but am experiencing an Incomplete response error via the web browser:

http://tenklakes.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/

I have tried `rake secrets` to generate a new `secret_key_base` for `production` in my `secrets.yml` file with no luck.

Secrets.yml :

`development:`
`secret_key_base:c70c590cfe799087c47528016ab49a1a8e57fe2eb851639e27e2ea66f92f241a0400b3d4247e3d61a6c82818dd3988825deeb66e783ba90cfccfbc0c500d6dbd`

`test:
secret_key_base: 08b1ebf5defee2eb1ad196e9780ae118f256c9f40f40f76674451dac4dfb1c42b75f04d22ee264644711de4e547ac8f58031e88f09c5c7223834b99230fb205c`

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

when I run `curl http:0.0.0.0:3000` I receive the following from Passenger:

`Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-09 04:52:43 +0000
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"internal"=>true}
  Rendering /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

NGINX error.log :

> [ 2016-10-09 04:49:44.8271 45647/7fe3b30d4700 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:112 ]: [Client 1-3] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
>   App 45674 stderr: [ 2016-10-09 04:49:56.0108 45754/0x0000000092d678(Worker 1) utils.rb:87 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 45754, thread 0x0000000092d678(Worker 1)):
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:513:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in`env_config'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:693:in `build_request'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:521:in`build_request'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in`process_request'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in`main_loop'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
>   App 45674 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in`block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'

I am out of ideas to get this working - is there anything else I should be checking?

EDIT: Here is what I get when running 'grep -r ENV *'

```
garrett@10klakes:~/lakemag$ grep -r ENV *
bin/bundle:ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
config/database.yml:  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
config/database.yml:#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
config/database.yml:  password: <%= ENV['LAKEMAG_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
config/puma.rb:threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
config/puma.rb:port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
config/puma.rb:environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
config/puma.rb:# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
config/environments/production.rb:  # config.secret_key_base =   ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
config/environments/production.rb:  config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
config/environments/production.rb:  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config/environments/production.rb:  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
config/boot.rb:ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
config/secrets.yml:  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

test/test_helper.rb:ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

Comment: To solve this issue check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395157/incomplete-response-received-from-application/47234911#47234911

Answer (score 0):

For `production` mode you have to set all `ENV` (environment) variables named in any ruby or config file. For example within `secrets.yml` Rails expects an environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE`. You didn't set this variable and now Rails does not start up in `production` mode.

You are using asure as hosting provider. So you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608769/how-and-where-to-define-an-environment-variable-on-azure)
to setup environment variables for azure. In short:

> Add a app setting in "App settings" section

You can use `rake secret` to generate a new key and use it for the environment variable.

One more hint. `secrets.yml` has its name for a reason. You should not post secrets from this file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jack!

Would this still be the case if I am not running rails in a cloud instance, but in a standalone VM?

Comment: Yes, it's recommended for production to use environment variables for confidential settings. This way confidential settings don't go into your repo. Further more it has some advantages for deployment (have a look https://12factor.net/). If you want, you can replace all `ENV` entries within your code, but I would recommend against it.

Comment: Hi Jack. Which files should I be looking at to remedy my problem?

Comment: I don't know. Try `grep -r ENV *` wihtin your `Rails.root`.

Comment: It seems like you have to setup `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` , `ENV['LAKEMAG_DATABASE_PASSWORD']` and maybe `ENV['PORT']`

Answer (score 0):

After much research the problem was in the hba_config file. md5 permissions needed to be set to "trust" instead.

I am not sure if this solution is a "complete" fix, but it worked in my case.

Comment: Hey there! I'm having the same issue but I don't have hba_config file. Is that a generic file or did you create that file? Thank you in advance.