# "Incomplete response received from application"

Tags: ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-14.04, passenger

I am using rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2. My application was running smoothly, but suddenly it started to show this message "Incomplete response received from application" randomly. Sometimes it works after refresh sometimes not.

I have deployed it using passenger + apache in ubuntu 14.04 server

Any Suggestion is welcomed. I am stuck here

update: I got this from the log file

```
Exception RuntimeError in Passenger RequestHandler's client socket (can't modify string; temporarily locked)
```

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241053/incomplete-response-received-from-application-from-nginx-passenger) answer? Probably it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I have checked it, but didn't help me