# Action Mailer failing to execute method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

```
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.1.5
```

I am trying to use ActionMailer to send an email to a number of recipients, but I want the recipients to be all in the :Bcc field.

In my conttollers/communications_controller.rb, I have:

```
  def create
    @communication = Communication.new(communication_params)
    @message_elements = construct_message_body(communication_params)
    @communication.message = @message_elements.to_json
    @communication.originator_id = current_user.id
    users_email_groups = users_emails
    @communication.recipients = users_email_groups.to_json
    respond_to do |format|
      if @communication.save
        users_email_groups.each do |recipients|
          logger.info("Recipients - start:")
          logger.info(recipients)
          MyMailer.communication_to_all_users(subject, recipients, message_elements).deliver_later
        end
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Email was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my models/my_mailer.rb, I have:

```
  def communication_to_all_users(subject, recipients, message_elements)
    logger.info("Module: #{__FILE__} - Line: #{__LINE__}")
    @message_elements = message_elements
    mail(:subject => subject,
         :to => Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
         :bcc => recipients)
  end
```

When the code is run, I get the message:

```
Incomplete response received from application
```

And in the log file, I have:

```
Processing by CommunicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "communication"=>{"subject"=>"Test Message - 2018-04-05 04:58", "paragraph_one"=>"Para 1 test", "paragraph_two"=>"", "paragraph_three"=>"", "paragraph_four"=>"", "paragraph_five"=>"", "signature"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
    SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
    SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`email` FROM `users`
    INSERT INTO `communications` (`subject`, `message`, `originator_id`, `recipients`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test Message - 2018-04-05 04:58', '[\"Para 1 test\"]', 1, '[[\"adam@xxxx.com\",\"eve@xxxx.org\"]]', '2018-04-09 00:10:34', '2018-04-09 00:10:34')
Recipients - start:
["adam@xxxx.com","eve@xxxx.org"]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

Based on the log file, it looks like the method communication_to_all_users is never called, and up until that point, it's all fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: while testing, try using just `deliver` instead of `deliver_later`. You can change it back once you're sure it's all working properly.

Comment: I already tried deliver

Comment: Good, it wasn't a suggestion for fixing the problem, but a suggestion for giving us better output while we're debugging your problem. Did it give the same error/output in the console? Can you show us more of the stacktrace (that usually is printed in the logfiles after the main error message)?

Comment: Have you also looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241053/incomplete-response-received-from-application-from-nginx-passenger/29456249

Comment: @TarynEast The log was the same in both cases, and I posted everything in the log file.

Comment: Also, no Phusion Passenger is not the issue. The app is running fine, with the exception of this error. As clear from the logger.info statements I placed inside the methods, that the ActionMailer method does not get executed at all

Comment: Does `Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username` return something meaningful when you check it in the console?

Comment: yes, it returns what it's supposed to. That's not the problem

Comment: Ok we need the stacktrace from the error. So you need to fix logging to figure out how to get it to produce the stacktrace. This means debug-level, or running it in the console and catching the error and displaying the stacktrace yourself. Find the way.

Comment: When bug-chasing, don't assume *anything* is as you think it is. Always re-test the obvious things, even if you think they're working. Even if they are so obviously simple they couldn't possibly be the problem... Nobody is immune to the small errors. Every assumption must be bash-tested. So instead of "yes it's working as expected" or "no it's not the issue" run it again, and tell me what the output is. I'm not being a PITA I'm being rigorous :)

Comment: Running as expected, means it produced the email address stored in the secrets file. Not sure what you mean by find the way

Comment: I meant I can't dictate how to get to the stacktrace... but there are some options to try and you'll need to find the one that works... :) if it's not automatically coming up in the console, then trying upping the debug-level for your log. try tailing your logfile instead of just looking in the console output. If that fails then try stepping through your code with pry, or run the code in your rails console (`rails c` instead of `rails s` and literally running it with a begin/rescue and catch the exception and manually print out the stacktrace :)