# Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment on Ubuntu 18.04 server (Rails 6.0), multiple topics tried

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, ubuntu-18.04

This topic has a **SOLUTION** embeded at the end.

## PROBLEM

I'm deploying for the first time a Rails app on a VPS on Ubuntu 18.04. with Nginx.
I followed the good tutorial of [Gorails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzEEfAj45zw) "Deploy Ruby on Rails To Production in 2019".
Everything worked, until I had the "Incomplete response received from application" page.

I checked the nginx logs on `/var/log/nginx/error.log`and saw the typical message "Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`"

As the method of Gorails didn't seems to work (after a `bundle exec rails secret` on his console app-side, he add a file /my_website/.rbenv-vars with a SECRET_KEY_BASE line, filled with the generated secret key), I decided to follow the multiples topics answering to this question.
Here is the thing, I'm not sure if the followings steps are the goods one.

1. I run `bundle exec rails secret`on my console, server-side, as deploy user. So I have my GENERATED_KEY_1
2. I add to `~/.bashrc` : `export SECRET_KEY_BASE="GENERATED_KEY_1"`
3. I `source ~/.bashrc`
4. I check my key with `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`, and I have the good key displayed (GENERATED_KEY_1)
5. I edited my credential file as

```
development:
  secret_key_base: ORIGINAL_KEY

test:
  secret_key_base: ORIGINAL_KEY

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

and added Dotenv to my Gemfile, required it in application.rb

But none of this worked, after restarted nginx server.
So I restarted the previous step, with the root-user.

But again, it failed.
My questions are:

- what I am missing ?
- How can I know, if it's searching the key in the good place, as I have always the same error message ?
- Which key am I suppose to generate ? App-side ? Server-side ? As root or deploy user ?
- Do I have something else to configure in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default ? (I saw on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259581/10717993) that this guys changed a `rails_env production; to rails_env development;` but I haven't any rails line)

Thank you, I'm a little bit desperate ^^

## SOLUTION

During my many tests, I logged with the root user, and run `EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit`. This command had generated a `master.key`, which doesn't exist on your Github repo.

But first, I didn't modified it. I think that was the main problem, as the application use it to decrypt your `credentials.yml.enc` file. When I understood it, I edited the `master.key` with the content of the `master.key` on my computer app.

Even after editing `credentials.yml.enc`with `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`, this solution works. This corresponds to the answer of [Lyzard Kyng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11801415/lyzard-kyng), even if it's a bit different.

I can't run `EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit`with the deploy user, it doesn't work.

Comment: Nginx has its own shell environment, it doesn't read your profile's `~/.bashrc`. So if you're using Dotenv you should put `SECRET_KEY_BASE="GENERATED_KEY_1"` to `.env.production` file under your app's root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails 5.2 and later uses encrypted credentials for storing sensitive app's information, which includes `secret_key_base` by default. These credentials are encrypted with the key stored in `master.key` file. Git repository, generated by default Rails application setup, includes `credentials.yml.enc` but ignores `master.key`. After the deployment, which usually involves `git push`, *Rails production environment* should be augmented with this key some way.

So you have two options. You can securely upload `master.key` to production host via `scp` or `sftp`. Or you can establish *shell environment* variable `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` within the context of a user that runs `rails server` process. The former option is preferred, but as you have `dotenv-rails` gem installed, you'd create `.env.production` file under app's root and put there a line

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY="your_master-key_content"
```

Don't forget to ensure that gem `dotenv-rails` isn't restricted within `Gemfile` by *development* and *test* Rails environments.

By the way since `passenger` module ver. 5.0.0 you can [set *shell environment* variables](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var) right from `nginx.conf`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer ! Before your answer, I tried to run ```EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit ``` with the root user, which created a master.key. That was maybe the main problem. I came back on this 1 hour after, and edited the file with the master.key of my application on my computer. Seems that it solved the problem, as even after edited the credentials.yml.enc file, I can't no more have the same issue. But I'll keep your 2nd answer for the next time ! Thank you again

Answer (score 6):

run `rake secret` in your local machine and this will generate a key for you

make `config/secrets.yml` file

add the generated secret key here

```
production:
 secret_key_base: asdja1234sdbjah1234sdbjhasdbj1234ahds…
```

and redeploy the application after commiting

i had the same issue and resolved by this method.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, unfortunately, Rails > 5.0 doesn't have any secrets.yml, as it's now a credential.yml.enc encrypted, can be edit with ```rails credentials:edit```. But anyway, do you edit it on server side, or app side ? With which key ? Original, or generated on server ?

Comment: its ok with the versions, if it doesnt have  a file just make `secrets.yml` in your config folder, i did also in rails 5 , i did some edits, please try

Comment: And is it supposed to have a master.key on the server app ? Which key is it ? Original or new one ?

Comment: Ok, will try, but which key ? ^^ The original or the generated ?

Comment: generated key using the command `rake secret` in your local machine

Comment: As root user, or deploy user ?

Comment: doesnt matter which user

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, you solved the answer !!! But isn't it unsecure to do it ?

Comment: i think this will not compromise with the safety of the deployed application

Comment: Make sure you're `.gitignore` the file `config/secrets.yml`

Comment: @LyzardKyng That would just mean the secret key for production would not be in the remote repo, thus making it not work in production. You would only do this if you are using a bare value for local and then switching to an `ENV` before pushing to the repo, adding the `.gitignore` then switching it back to the bare key to use on local.

Comment: @OBrooks If your repo is publicly visible then it absolutely is.

Comment: Don't use `secrets.yml`, it has been deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more secure to generate your key on the server and use it there, rather than push it to your repo from a local machine.

Instead of `~/.bashrc` do this for using environment variables;

1. As `root` user, navigate to the `#` directory (can probably just use `cd ..`)
2. Enter `nano home/<yourAppUser>/.bash_profile` to navigate to (and create) the file to store the `ENV`
3. As you have already, just write this in the file: `export SECRET_KEY_BASE="GENERATED_KEY_1"`

You can store your database password here as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried a different solution, as related to my edit, with a master.key created on the server. Even after edit my credentials.yml.enc in  ```<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>```, I can't have the same issue anymore, I don't know why. But I'll keep the try on your solution for the next time ! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

1_ Set credentials with

```
rails credentials:edit
```

2_ Upload **master.key** file to your production server.

If deploy with capistrano, copy **master.key** to shared folder (shared_path) and then add this to **deploy.rb**:

```
namespace :config do
   task :symlink do
      on roles(:app) do
        execute :ln, "-s #{shared_path}/master.key #{release_path}/config/master.key"
      end
   end
end

after 'deploy:symlink:shared', 'config:symlink'
```

Comment: Step 1 is unclear. *Where* do I run this command; my computer or the server. If on the server, what directory? I get `rails: command not found` when running it in the `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on `rails credentials:edit`, the file indentation were not accurate which gave the error on deployment. So make sure the indentation is correct on your local before deploying.

Comment: can you be more specific about how the indentation should look?

Comment: This answer was from a long time ago. I don't remember much, but I believe I was talking about the indentation on your YAML file. You should be really careful with the indentation on YAML file. @LelandReardon