# Error when trying to run rails application on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm am working as a part of a team for a school project. We are using Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 6.0.2.1. I have pulled the master branch from GitHub, but when I try to run the application I get this error:

ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment

I have looked online and found that the old solution was to change the config/secrets.yml file, but rails 6 no longer has that file, and instead has an encoded credentials.yml.enc file that has the same functionality. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing \`secret\_key\_base\` for 'production' environment on Ubuntu 18.04 server (Rails 6.0), multiple topics tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290160/missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment-on-ubuntu-18-04-server-r)

Comment: Do you have a `master.key` in the `config` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails > 5.2 introduced a new feature for securing credentials. For this rails uses a `master.key` in `config` folder which is usually added to `.gitignore` so that it stays secure and doesn't get pushed to git.

This `master.key` is used to encrypt or decrypt content from the `credentials.yml.enc` file which you found.

If you are working on a team then the project creator will have to share this `master.key` file to you personally or you have to create a new `credentials.yml.enc`. You can do it using the below command -

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

This will create a new `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` in your machine but the changes made by your teammates in the `credentials.yml.enc` will be lost. To avoid that hassle just get the `master.key` from your teammate and put it in the `config`. folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the **config.require_master_key = true**    #in config/environments/production.rb

You can go to this link to check this in detail:- https://blog.engineyard.com/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2

I hope this will work for you.